# Fetching incorrect value in Hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm extracting values of alphabets as key from hashmap `set`, but only for key `"s"`, getting value as for previous key i.e. `"r"`.

Don't know why it is fetching value of previous key, only for key `"s"`.

Below is the code.

```
    for (String x : arrName) {
        if (set.containsKey(x)) {
            if (x.equals("s")) {
                sum += 1;
            } else {
                sum += set.get(x);
            }
        }
    }
```

using if else to avoid this.

Comment: Please give definition of `arrName` and `set`. And what are you trying to do ? Also you say you don't understand why letter `s` is handlede differently, the code seems pretty clear about that, you have an if that check for `s`

Comment: Please clarify what is your problem and which result you expect.  Your code calculates the sum of _all_ values contained in the hashmap `set` and only for letter `"s"` it counts 1 instead of actual value.  Thus, if `set` is `{"s"=3, "r"=1}`, the sum will be 2,  Which result would be correct for you?

Comment: i;m usi;ng if else statement for s, to get the correct value, if i remove that i would give me incorrect value.

Comment: set is a hashmap of alphabets assigned with some numeric values, what i'm trying to do is, take a string and calculate its value based on the aplpabets in it.

Comment: aarrName is an arraylist with the characters in the name i'm generating value of

Comment: In set s = 1, but while fetching the value it is taking 9.